# CCRC checkin with checked out and hijacked files

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm trying to commit a number of files

rcleartool.bat ci file1.cxx file2.cxx

only file1.cxx is checkedout
file2.cxx is hijacked

This commit checks in file1.cxx but leave file2 unchecked in giving me a warning

Is there a way to say "check in all files, including the hijacked ones I supply on the command line" or do I have to go through all the hijacked files, check them out and immediately check them back in?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`cleartool checkin` command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm?lang=en) does not mention [hijacked files](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_hijack.htm?lang=en), you would need two passes:

- one for [converting hijacked files in checkout files](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccview_hijack_conv.htm) with [`checkout -usehijack`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-4&lang=en)
- one for checking, which will does nothing for the hijacked files,

Comment: that would be the procedure to revert a hijacked file right? i was looking at more being able to checkin the hijacked file but I think you are correct I am going to have to go through 2 passes, one to checkout the hijacked file with the -use/hijack argument to not remove my changes to the hijacked file then check that one in with the rest

Comment: @MyDeveloperDay I agree. I misread your question. I have edited the answer accordingly, with links to the official documentation.